# When are static fields initialized in Java?

Tags: java, singleton

In this basic implementation of Singleton, when is the `new Singleton1()` call actually occuring (marked with `*`?

```
public final class Singleton1 {

    private Singleton1() { }

    private static Singleton1 instance = new Singleton1(); // (*) When does this happen?
                                                           //     Before calling getInstance() from the client?

    public static Singleton1 getInstance() {
        return instance;
    }
}
```

Comment: Yes. Guaranteed to happen *before* `getInstance()`. An `enum` is the more usual way to implement `Singleton` these days.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Static fields are populated when the class is first loaded by the JVM (See [JLS 12.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4)). So yes, `instance` will be populated before `getInstance()` can be called.